# How to solve $ e^x = \frac{e^{\frac{x}{2}}}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help with the following equation:

$$ e^x = \frac{e^{\frac{x}{2}}}{2}$$

I need to find $x$ and I don't know how.

I have tried replacing $e^x$ with $t$ and it didn't work.
I sat on this for around an hour and I cant figure it out.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: $e^{0.5x}=(e^x)^{0.5}$.

Comment: replace $x$ with $2t$

Comment: @DavidMitra So i get 0.5x = 0.5x

Comment: As usual, start by moving all the $x$'s to one side to get $e^x/e^{x/2}=1/2$.

Answer (score 5):

Put $$y=e^{x/2}.$$  Then the equation we must solve becomes $$y^2=\frac12 y.$$  By inspection, we have $y=0$ or $y=\frac12$.  $y=0$ gives no solution for $x$ because the function $e^t$ is everywhere positive.  So the only solution has $y=e^{x/2}=\frac12$ and so $x = 2\ln\frac12$.

Answer (score 4):

We take the ***natural log*** of both sides of the equation, and recall that $\ln(e^{ax}) = ax$, and that $\ln(a/b) = \ln a - \ln b$.

$$\ln(e^x) = \ln\left(\frac{e^{(1/2)x}}{2}\right) \iff x = \ln(e^{(1/2)x} - \ln(2) \iff x = 0.5x - \ln 2 \iff \frac x2 = -\ln 2 \iff x = -2\ln 2 = -(-2)\ln(1/2)= 2\ln(1/2)$$

Comment: x=0.5x ? Thats what I got..

Comment: @user134456 no. you have $$e^x = \frac{e^{\frac{x}{2}}}{2}$$.

now when you take the log of the left side, you get $x$. on taking the log of the right side, apply $$\ln\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) = \ln(y) - \ln(x)$$

Comment: No, the right-hand side is given by $\ln\left(0.5e^{0.5x}\right) = \ln(0.5)+\cdot 0.5x = 0.5x - \ln(2)$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Use these equalities
$$\frac{a^x}{a^y}=a^{x-y}$$
and
$$e^x=\alpha\iff x=\ln \alpha$$